# Make image sharp at lower resolutions?

Tags: display, fonts, resolution

I suspect there's not an answer for my issue after investigating for a while, but I figured I might as well ask anyway. I recently bought an Asus G751J (with a GeForce GTX 970M card, Windows 8.1), a 17" screen with a 1920 x 1080 native resolution, which I find it to be a little too small for my taste (text and app sizes in general). So far the only two options I've found are not ideal:

1. Lower the resolution to a 1600 x 900 display. Very straightforward, albeit the image is not as sharp in contrast to its native resolution. From what I've found, there's no way to fix this blurriness (is there?)
2. Change the Windows DPI to 125% to make text and desktop icons larger - keeps the sharp image albeit it doesn't reflect on all apps. The chrome address bar, for instance, is still the same size; or text is displaced from its original location because the font increased but the window size didn't, so I wouldn't call this an ideal solution either.

Is there another solution I may have overlooked to "fix" this problem? Or is there no other choice but to get used to it?

Comment: @Psycogeek It's Windows 8.1, I can't seem to find the "Windows Color" option under Personalization.

Comment: in 8.1 text size adjustment is right there on the same display screen as DPI, i assume you have already seen it.

Comment: @Psycogeek Yes, but I explain in point 2 why this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Fitment in things when the font size increases , sometimes after closing the program and reopening it will re-fit, sometimes re-booting might be nessisary to see how things are fully redrawn. Some stuff will Never fit right via DPI changes, font changes.  So giving them a chance to re-arrange everything takes even longer to see if it works proper, then it still doesn't :-) sometimes

Answer (score 0):

For a reason, I suggest you to lower it to 1900 times 1065 or 1839 times 1030 depending on what you want, but don't change the dpi higher than 100. Keep dpi at 100

Comment: Can you share what that reason is, and explain why this will solve the problem?

Comment: My Chromebook has 2048x1152 resolution and only 10". So sharp. And